# How to checkout git branch that was created from the GitHub website?

Tags: git, github

So I've created a quick change on the GitHub repo, but it requires more work, adding unit tests, and running the build. So I have new branch created with web interface:

https://github.com/jcubic/prism/tree/patch-1

But when I use `git pull`, in the terminal, I have nothing was changed. When I use `git branch -a` I've got:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  scheme-operators
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/gh-pages
  remotes/upstream/master
```

no branch `patch-1`. I have this in .git/config:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:jcubic/prism.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

How I can update my local repo with stuff that is on GitHub?

**EDIT**:

It may be a bug on the GitHub side. It was reported and I'm waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

> ```
> [remote "origin"]
>         url = git@github.com:jcubic/prism.git
>         fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
> ```

is the problem.  Note the `fetch` line here; this is the result of using `git clone --single-branch` or one of its several equivalents.

Having made a single-branch clone that you want to be a multi-branch clone, the recommended method is to use `git remote` to update the set of branches to fetch.  I personally prefer to just run `git config --edit` and use my editor, but:

```
git remote set-branches origin "*"
```

will do the trick, and avoids some possible pitfalls that might occur with `git config --edit`.

Your real goal here is to make these three lines read:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:jcubic/prism.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Note the change to the third line: we now have our (local) Git (our Git software, running on this repository) call up their Git as usual, but this time, when *their* Git—their software on their repository—lists out all their branches, *our* Git says "yes! I'll take all of those!"  With just `master` listed, our Git picks over their branches: *Oh, hm, patch-1, that's not interesting.  "feature", no, pass!  "fix-23"?  No way.  "master": ah, that's the only one we care about: yes please!*

When our Git says it *doesn't want* any of their branches *except* `master`, they only *send* us the pieces we need to make our `origin/master`—our memory of their `master`—and not any of the pieces we need to make our own `origin/patch-1`, for instance.  So by explicitly *rejecting their* `patch-1`, you never get an `origin/patch-1`, and hence cannot create your own `patch-1` from their `patch-1`.

Undoing the single-branch-ness fixes *all* of this, and now:

```
git fetch origin
```

gets, from them, *all* of their branches, turning them into all your remote-tracking names, `origin/*`.

#### About `git fetch --all`

[hreikin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69686270/1256452) mentions `git fetch --all` (and `git fetch --multiple`; there are other additional variants).  These are sometimes useful when you have more than one *remote*.

A *remote* is a name-and-URL set, and you do in fact have more than one remote:

> ```
> $ git branch -a
> * master
>   scheme-operators
>   remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
>   remotes/origin/master
>   remotes/upstream/gh-pages
>   remotes/upstream/master
> ```

This shows us that you have remotes named `origin` and `upstream`.  These each represent *different Git repositories* to which you connect *your* Git repository.

Sometimes, you have your Git call up the Git over at `origin`, to see what branches and commits *they* have.  These go into your repository under your `origin/*` names—currently, `origin/master` only, because you've told your Git that all other branches are too boring for words.

Other times, you have your Git call up the Git over at `upstream`, to see what branches and commits *they* have.  These go into your repository under your `upstream/*` names.

With `git fetch`, you direct *your* Git to call up *one other Git*.  Which one?  Well, that depends: each branch, in your repository, is allowed to list one thing that Git calls an *upstream*.  This name is a little bit unfortunate, since it's also the name of one of your remotes.  But the upstream of your `master` branch is typically your `origin/master`: your *remote-tracking name* for the branch `master` on the Git you call `origin`.

The default, when you run `git fetch`, is to call up the Git that holds the branch that your *current* branch is using as its remote-tracking name.  So if you're on your `master`, and its upstream is set to `origin/master`, your Git will run `git fetch origin` when you run `git fetch` without naming *which* Git to fetch *from*.

If you run `git fetch upstream`, though, your Git will fetch from `upstream` instead of `origin`.  Or, you could create some other branch whose upstream is set to `upstream/master` or `upstream/gh-pages`:

```
git branch upmaster upstream/master
git checkout upmaster
git fetch
```

and now your Git would fetch from `upstream` (the remote named `upstream`), because the upstream of `upmaster` is `upstream/master`, which uses `upstream` as its remote.  (Confused yet?  If not, Git has still other confusing terms to use!  Seriously, these historical accidents have made quite a mess here.)

Anyway, this particular thing—where `git fetch` fetches from *one* remote—works great when there's *only one remote* (usually called `origin`).  But once you have two or more, it's nice to be able to fetch from *all* of them.

**That's what the `--all` flag is for.**  It means *fetch all remotes*.  It never means *fetch all branches:* the branches you get are per-remote, specified by that `fetch =` line.<sup>1</sup>  But in practice, it doesn't make a lot of sense to use `git fetch --all`, because there is another command:

```
git remote update
```

that means *fetch all*.  The `git remote` command has a lot more tuning options, with the idea of "group" fetches from your most-commonly-used remotes for instance.  These *can* all be done by `git fetch` but `git remote` is the command that's really aimed at this kind of fine detail.

The bottom line, as it were, is:

- use `git fetch` to fetch from the remote for *this* branch;
- use `git remote update` to fetch from all remotes, if you have more than one.

With these as general rules, and knowledge of how upstreams and `fetch =` lines work, you're now all set.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, you can have more than one line per remote.  You can also *override* these lines using a *refspec* on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `git fetch` first.

This downloads all branches and their commit histories from GitHub (note that `git pull` also runs `git fetch` but also a `git merge`).

After running `git fetch`, you can see the remote branch with `git branch -a`.

Then, you can check it out using `git checkout patch-1` or `git checkout -b patch-1 remotes/origin/patch-1`.

Comment: It doesn't work `git branch -a` don't return branch `patch-1` Maybe I need to clone the repo again.

Comment: Are you sure you executed `git fetch` before that? Just `git fetch`, not `git fetch main` or similar.

Comment: Yes, I did `git fetch` it's the same as `git pull` If the current branch didn't changed. Something is wrong normal git commands don't work, I know how to fetch the branch.

Comment: What if you run `git fetch origin`?

Comment: The same, it may be a GitHub bug. I've reported this to them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the branches from the remote first.

- To fetch all branches from the remote you are tracking locally you can run `git fetch --all`
- To fetch from a specific remote, origin in this case, run `git fetch origin`
- To fetch from multiple remotes, origin and upstream in this case, run `git fetch --multiple origin upstream`
- Then to view all the branches run `git branch -a`
- Then to checkout the branch run `git checkout nameofnewbranch`

The documentation for 'git fetch' is available [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch).

Comment: `git branch` only shows local branches.

Comment: This doesn't work `git fetch --all` only fetched upstream content.

Comment: @jcubic try ```git fetch origin``` i think the previous command only fetches from the remote you are tracking, sorry.

Comment: Nothing, I've reported this to GitHub maybe it's a bug on their end.

Comment: @jcubic hmmm, ok one last idea is to try ```git fetch --multiple origin upstream```

Comment: Still nothing, my branch is not visible.

Comment: After reading the docs, one very final thing you could try would be ```git fetch origin patch-1``` to fetch just that branch from that remote, something could be wrong with your config file, the docs show a typical one with the following content:  

[remote "origin"]
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Comment: `git fetch --all` is nearly always the wrong answer: it doesn't do what people think it does.

Comment: @torek thanks for providing such a detailed answer and explanation of how things work, i have up-voted it